# Row locking failed when working on weblogic cluster environment (multiple nodes inside the cluster)

Tags: sql, jpa, weblogic

My application is deployed on a weblogic 9 cluster environment with 2 nodes and connecting to MS SQL Server 2005 using persistence provider toplink. The application deployed is written in Java.

My application needs to do a simple operation when serving request A:

1. begin transaction
2. Select entries from table A and place row locking on them
3. Process them
4. Update table A with the result.
5. end transaction

The java code is like:

```
EntityManager em =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceLevelPU").createEntityManager;
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

// step 2
em.createNativeQuery("select * from Table_A with(updlock, rowlock) where id = 123");
List<List<Object>> results = (List<List<Object>>) query.getResultList();

//step 3
SomeOperation(results);

// step 4, using the results from step 3
em.createNativeQuery("update Table_A set Column A = 'something' where id = 123");

// step 4
em.flush();
transaction.commit();
```

It seems that if I launch request A on Node 1 and Node 2 at the same time, both Node will be able to proceed to step 3 which is out of my expectation. As I am expecting the database should be already locked by the Node (e.g. Node 1) goes through the step 2 first (because `with(updlock, rowlock)`), while the later one should be blocked until the first transaction is committed.

May I know if I got something wrong? Many thanks for the help

---

Thanks for your response. After some more investigation, I found the following:

1. Our method is actually invoked by the MDB
2. the persistence.xml is as following

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceLevelPU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
       <jta-data-source>TestDB</jta-data-source>
           <properties>
               <property name="toplink.cache.type.default" value="" />
           </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

So I am wondering now:
1. Is it an application-managed or container-managed transaction manager?
2. in both case, how can I handle the transaction within the application? use UserTransaction or EntityTransaction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both will get to step 3 and complete, the second transaction should wait until the first commits before it goes through though.

It is odd if you are not seeing this.  Are you sure row 123 exists?  Are they connecting to the same database, do you have transactions configured correctly?  If you try just with(updlock) does it work?  It may be something related to how your database is configured, maybe try the same in a database shell.

Instead of the select, you could also try updating the row (set some column equal to itself), this should ensure a row lock is acquired.

Answer (score 0):

From your persistence.xml you are using JTA transactions, but from your code you are using JPA EntityManager transactions.  You cannot use both, only one or the other.

If you are using an MDB, you should be using an injected JTA managed EntityManager.  You should not use JPA transactions, and the MDB should automatically start/end a JTA transaction.

My guess is you have not set a "toplink.target-server", which you must do, to enable JTA integration on WLS.  I'm not sure TopLink Essentials shipped a WLS server, so you might want to upgrade to EclipseLink.

If you want to use JPA EntityManager transactions, then set transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" in your persistence.xml.